# How to grab content from one column with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to grab the contents from one column only. but it's grabbing that one column as well as the rest of the row content and displaying it. How can I just grab only the age column?

```js
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
var myTab = document.getElementById('empTable');

// LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {

  // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
  var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

  // LOOP THROUGH EACH CELL OF THE CURENT ROW TO READ CELL VALUES.
  for (var j = 2; j < objCells.length; j++) {
    info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(j).innerHTML;
  }

  info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ',';

}
```

```css
th,
td,
p,
input {
  font: 14px Verdana;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Read Data from HTML Table uisng JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="empTable">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Alpha</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>Bravo</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p id="info"></p>
```

**Outcome:**

```
37 Blue, 29 Red,
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
37, 29
```

Any help and explanation is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

**bfox**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through all the cells of each row, you need to only process the 3rd cell of each row, here is an example:

```js
var myTab = document.getElementById('empTable');

var ages = [];

for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
  var currentRow = myTab.rows[i];
  var ageCell = currentRow.cells[2];
  ages.push(ageCell.textContent);
}

var info = document.getElementById('info');
info.innerHTML = ages.join();
```

```css
th,
td,
p,
input {
  font: 14px Verdana;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Read Data from HTML Table uisng JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="empTable">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Alpha</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>Bravo</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p id="info"></p>
```

What this does is to loop through each row and add the 3rd cell's text content to the `ages` array, once all the rows are processed, the `#info` element's inner HTML is set to a string representation of the `ages` array (`.join()` just creates a string which contains the string representation of each element of the array separated by a comma).

Comment: Thanks, Titus. I actually used your coding for my project. I knew I was close but your code made a lot of sense. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through all elements of objCells after index 2 which is returning objCells[2] (37) and objCells[3] (blue)

just access objCells[2] like so

```
for (var j = 2; j < objCells.length; j++) {
   info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(j).innerHTML;
}
```

Should be

```
info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(2).innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, the second for-loop is reading all cells starting from index-2.
This is causing all the unnecessary values to get concatenated.

The problem can be fixed by replacing the for-loop with an assignment statement in an if-condition.

Additionally, the trailing comma can be avoided by using an array instead of updating the inner-html of the result element inside the loop.

**Here is the working code with the suggested change:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Read Data from HTML Table uisng JavaScript</title>
    </head>
<body>
      <table id="empTable">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Employee Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>01</td>
          <td>Alpha</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>02</td>
          <td>Bravo</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <p id="info"></p>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
        var myTab = document.getElementById('empTable');


        // Declare a result array
        var result = []

        // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
        for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {

            // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
            var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

            // Add the content of second cell to result array
            if(objCells.length >= 2) {
                result.push(objCells.item(2).innerHTML);
            }    
        }

        // Show the result array in the info element
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = result
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
ID  Employee Name   Age     Color
01  Alpha   37  Blue
02  Bravo   29  Red

37,29
```